# Difference between <Textbox Text={Binding} /> and <Textbox><Textbox.Text><Binding>

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtAppName" Text="{Binding XPath=setting[@name\=\'SiteID\']/value}"/>
```

This works just fine (DataContext on the window is set to an XMLDataProvider).

However, when I change the syntax to this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtAppName">
     <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding XPath="setting[@name\=\'AppName\']/value">
        </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

The binding does not work.  I'm changing it to this so I can add validation but I can't seem to get the binding to work with or without the validation.  There are no syntax errors when I compile but the data does not show in the textbox.  I'm hoping I'm missing something simple.  I'm using VS 2008.

Comment: Look at the output window; if a binding error is occurring in it'll be displayed there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inline version you have to account for the specific markup extension syntax, you probably should drop the escape characters:

```
<Binding XPath="setting[@name='AppName']/value">
```